# Subscript Out of Range Error When Closing Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently trying to edit a macro that opens a base file [myFile], runs a separate macro in that base file. By running this base file, an entirely new workbook is created [myFile2]. The goal is to take myFile2, do some resizing, move some sheets around, etc., and create a differently formatted report [myFile3].

Everything is working fine until I go to close the workbooks, where I'm getting a subscript out of range error.

This wasn't my original code. I'm now editing it, and I don't have access to the original author. The word 'FALSE' is by each of the workbook close statements, and I'm also wondering if that is related to save changes or something else that could be contributing to the problem?

```vb
myPath = "\this\is\a\file\path"
myFile = "base.xlsm"

myPath2 = "\this\is\another\path"
myFile2 = Format(Date, "yymmdd") & "-base_results" & ".xlsm"

myPath3 = "\this\is\a\third\path"
myFile3 = "formatted_base_results" & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy") & ".xlsm"

'open workbook to run macros
Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath2 & "\" & myFile2, UpdateLinks:=False)

'run macros in opened workbook
Application.Run ("'" & wkb.Name & "'!" & "MoveSheets")
DoEvents
Application.Run ("'" & wkb.Name & "'!" & "FormatSheets")
DoEvents
Application.Run ("'" & wkb.Name & "'!" & "NewDocument")
DoEvents

'close workbooks
'cant index by full file name

Workbooks(myFile).Close False
Workbooks("DailyBuildPrint - Avg Fare" & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy") & ".xlsm").Close False
Workbooks(myFile2).Close False
```

Comment: Which instruction is throwing the error? `Workbooks(myFile2).Close False` should be `wkb.Close SaveChanges:=False` (that optional argument indeed goes to a parameter named `SaveChanges`)

Comment: this line looks fishy: `Workbooks("DailyBuildPrint - Avg Fare" & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy") & ".xlsm").Close False` because it doesn't appear the code ever names a workbook by the name passed, but without seeing what the other code does, it's hard to say for sure

Comment: Rule of thumb, if you're dealing with workbook objects you've opened yourself, then you should have a `Workbook` object variable *somewhere* holding that reference (like `wkb` does) - when you have that, you don't need to hard-code file names or dereference workbooks from the `Workbooks` collection: just use the workbook variables.